# How to autofill other form fields upon click with PHP

Tags: php, autofill

I have a simple form right now:

```
<form action='<? echo $PHP_SELF;?>' method='POST'>
Username:<input type='text' name='username'><br>
Email:<input type='text' name='email'><br>
Posts:<input type='text' name='posts'><br>
Joindate<input type='text' name='join'><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

What I need is, when the user fills his username and does one of the following:
1.presses tab
2.Presses enter
3.clicks on a fetch button(fetch button does not exist now,i would like to know how to create it using javascript or anything else that suits my criteria)

Once he does any of the above it should automatically generate the remaining fields from the database.
The query would look like this:
         $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * from user where username =`$_POST['username']`");
         $row=mysql_fetch_assoc('$qry);
         echo $row['posts] and so on..

After it is autogenerated he can edit the fields and submit to update the database fields.

Here is my updated code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>
<label for="username">Username: </label>

<input type="text" id="username"  name="username" /> 
<button onclick="myrequest()">fetch</button>
<label for="posts">Posts: </label>
<input type="text" id="posts" name="posts"  size="20"/>
<label for="joindate">Joindate: </label>
<input type="text" id="joindate" name="joindate"  size="20"/>



<p><input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit" /></p>

</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="javascript/text>
function myrequest() {
var name = $('.username').val();
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://url.com/test/autofill.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    username: username
  }).success(function( responseObject ) {
    // assuming you have an array of stuff like name, id, email, etc.
    // now i populate another field from the ajax response
    $('.posts').val( responseObject.posts );
  });

} 
And then in the autofill.php

    //connect to database
    $name = $_GET['username'];
    $return = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$name' LIMIT 1");
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($return);
    $formattedData = json_encode($rows);
    print $formattedData;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a php endpoint (basically a url in which you can call your special php function, which returns only the data you want) that returns a json_encode'd array with all of the other fields' info.

Call that function via ajax when the first field either loses focus or changes (or a button is pressed), depending on your preference.

Then using javascript, use what you've gotten back from the ajax response to populate the other fields.

**autoFill.php**

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$return = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE username = '$name' LIMIT 1");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($return);
$formattedData = json_encode($rows);
print $formattedData;
```

**Javascript (using jquery)**
//gets the val from the first field

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function myrequest(e) {
        var name = $('.username').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/echo/json/", /* online, change this to your real url */
            data: {
                username: name
            },
            success: function( responseObject ) {
                alert('success');
                $('#posts').val( 'posts' );
                $('#joindate').val('testing join date');
                /*
                once you've gotten your ajax to work, then go through and replace these dummy vals with responseObject.whatever
                */
            },
            failure: function() {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    }

    $('#fetchFields').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        myrequest();
    });
});
```

Comment: wow..that is pretty new to me..can u provide with some examples. i tried googling it but cannot come up with something that would help me.

Comment: Thanks,in the php side do i have to call something like this?<form action='autoFill.php' method='GET'>
Username:<input type='text' name='username'">
 <input type="submit" name='fetch' value="Fetch" />

Comment: nope -- in the code you just provided, you've got method="GET" which basically tells the browser what http method to use when the page refreshes. Ajax also needs to know that because its not going to do a page refresh in the process. See my above JS code where it says 'method: "GET" '

Comment: I have once again updated my code above..this time there are no errors..but the page just refreshes with out returning anything..

Comment: please check that your markup for errors. I see that you have written <script type="text/javascript>   with no closing quotes... which means none of that javascript will be loaded / executed

Comment: ok i have fixed that part but the page still refreshes and does not return anything. is it because the fetch button acts as a submit button. Also how do i generate the other fields by pressing tab.

Comment: hahaha you seriously need to check your work. you wrote "javascript/text". ALSO, please actually attach that function to an event. obviously a function will not just spontaneously call itself without you telling it to.

Comment: wow i messed up real badly!..also what do you mean by attach it to an event. I am calling the javascript onclick method.

Comment: Thanks a lot kristian...i got it working except i am not able to retrieve the username field in autofill.php.If i manually enter the username in my query it works. I ll fix that issue myself. I owe you big time in helping me out!

Comment: You're welcome! you can start repaying me by marking my solution as complete. haha

Comment: there you go..thanks again..i had one question regarding the failure function,if i enter a invalid username,the database returns empty values, it does not give any error.instead it justs echoes 'success' and displays empty fields.

Comment: The success and failure functions in that ajax method are only referring to whether the actual ajax request / response was successful. It does not indicate that you did or did not get a certain type of data out of your sql query. You'd probably be getting an empty array. so inside of your success function, you can check the length of that array if you wish... and say that there was no user data found.. or something like that. its your choice. Please read the jQuery.ajax documentation for further understanding